# changing the value of savehist-minibuffer-history-variables in Emacs

Tags: function, variables, emacs, hook

It says on lines 129-130 of https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/savehist.el that the default behaviour is to determine the contents of `savehist-minibuffer-history-variables` while emacs is running. I indeed see in my `savehist-file` that this appears to be `yes-or-no-p-history`, `buffer-name-history` and a few other variables.

However, I would like to save *only* a specific history in emacs, namely that of `filesets-data`, implemented via

```
(setq savehist-additional-variables '(filesets-data))
```

It says on lines 59-60 of [savehist.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/savehist.el) that this can be achieved by using `savehist-save-hook` to change the value of `savehist-minibuffer-history-variables`.

I unfortunately cannot figure out how to do that. I have tried

```
(setq savehist-minibuffer-history-variables nil)
(add-hook 'savehist-save-hook 'savehist-minibuffer-history-variables)
```

in my `.emacs.d` but that yields an error message:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: savehist-minibuffer-history-variables
```

Any help on changing `savehist-minibuffer-history-variables` to be empty when exiting emacs is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you put on a hook is a *function*, not a variable (and not some other sexp).

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (setq savehist-minibuffer-history-variables nil))

(add-hook 'savehist-save-hook #'foo)
```

Comment: You are perfectly right, of course, @Drew. Thanks a million! It works like a dream, albeit without the `#` in `add-hook`. Why did you add that?

Comment: `#'` instead of `'` tells Emacs, including the byte compiler, that the thing quoted is a function. Knowing this it can (in principle) sometimes be a bit smarter or produce more efficient code. Plain `'` works fine, though. See the Elisp manual, node [Anonymous Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html). (`i #' TAB` in the manual takes you to that node in Info.)

Comment: I see. Thanks for this, @Drew!

Comment: Must the variable be set in the hook?  Would setq (before savehist-mode) not suffice?

Comment: @JohnH. Yes that should work, as the variable is global. (But it's generally better practice to do so after the variable's `defvar` has been evaluated, i.e., after savehist.el has been loaded, at least.)